# Ionic 2 how to use market templates

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm new to Ionic 2 and I've discovered templates and theme market, but I don't know how to use it.
Let's say I want to use this template: https://market.ionic.io/starters/event-app-and-maps ; one I've downloaded the zip file, how should I use it? Do I have to create a blank project and then add the downloaded folders in it? If so, is it possible for me to change some of the contents (let's say if I want to use just some of the content offered)?
Same question for themes: how can I integrate them in my project?

Answer (score 0):

First try to understand the app structure and what are the different types of files,folders and what is the use of them etc.. Without that you can not do anything.

Now coming to market themes.. Download the theme and go thru it. Normally most of the developers will provide a `how to use` guide. Follow  those steps or it will be much better if you implement on your own after understanding the code.